# SDL Snake slows down?

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I've been working on a clone of Snake using SDL but I've found that as I run the game it slows down. The snake starts moving quite fast but after a few turn it slows down quite a bit. I've been trying to figure out why but can't. :(
I assume it's got something to do with either the way I've tried to implement FPS or the update game function (where key handling takes place).

Here's where I'm trying to implement FPS:

```cpp
void run(){
    int SKIP_TICKS;;
    long next_game_tick = time(0);
    long sleep_time = 0;
    std::cout<<next_game_tick<<std::endl;

    while (!quit){
        SKIP_TICKS = 1000 / fps;

        updateGame();
        render();

        next_game_tick += SKIP_TICKS;
        sleep_time = next_game_tick - time(0);
        sleep_time *= 10;
        usleep(sleep_time);
    }
}
```

And here is my update game function:

```cpp
void updateGame(){
    SDL_Event event;

    if (!isFrutActive){
        doNewFruit();
    }

    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT){
            quit = true;
        }
        if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN){//Get keyboard input
            switch (event.key.keysym.sym){
                case SDLK_ESCAPE:   quit = true; break;

                case SDLK_UP:
                case SDLK_w:
                    ydir = -SPEED;
                    xdir = 0;
                    break;

                case SDLK_DOWN:
                case SDLK_s:
                    ydir = SPEED;
                    xdir = 0;
                    break;

                case SDLK_LEFT:
                case SDLK_a:
                    xdir = -SPEED;
                    ydir = 0;
                    break;

                case SDLK_RIGHT:
                case SDLK_d:
                    xdir = SPEED;
                    ydir = 0;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you drawing the whole snake each time? Or are you just drawing the new square?

Comment: Do you calculate the fps as number of renders per second?

Comment: Either way, I suspect that as you start with a relatively high fps, SKIP_TICKS has a low value at first but increases as your fps limiter kicks in, triggering a chain reaction.

Comment: @Propolys: fps is a set value of 30.

Comment: @sje397: I'm drawing the whole snake each time

Comment: It looks like you use `usleep` (µs) and you count in ms, but only multiply by 10. This means that you are not actually limiting your fps, so it probably only slows down with your rendering. Also, you should make sure `sleep_time` is not negative.

Comment: @ElderBug: Even when I multiply by 1000 I get the exact same problem. I set it to *= 10 because *= 1000 even with fps set to 60 it's to slow for how fast I would like my game to run at.

Comment: It is probable that your render function is way too slow. It would explain everything. Your *10 delay is basically too small to be observable (100 times too small). If your render function takes too long, your `sleep_time` will be negative and `usleep` will return an error. Also, for comparison, last time I did a snake game, 40 ticks per second was so fast it was nearly unplayable. It probably means that you aren't anywhere near 30 per sec.

Comment: Try to std::cout sleep_time each frame and see what you get.

Comment: @Propolys: It increases quite a lot.

Comment: Did you try using SDL_GetTicks instead of time(0)?

Comment: I've just added "next_game_tick = time(0);" right under where I call render() and it seems to keep the sleep_time at a constant rate now. But is this an accurate way of implementing FPS?

Comment: @Propolys: I've just tried using SDL_GetTicks instead of time(0) which actually works very well but when I press the X to quit the app I get this weird X-Code error where it highlights the line usleep(sleep_time); and says 'Thread 1: signal SIGTERM??? This doesn't happen when I press escape instead.

Comment: Do you handle tge SDL_Quit even type? Set quit to true on event.type==SDL_Quit

Comment: @Propolys: I've already done that. Taking another look it seems that when I click the X sleep_time for some reason becomes a negative. See here: https://goo.gl/F15SwN

Comment: 403 Forbidden. Try using something else like pastebein

Comment: http://bit.ly/1EfzXfk I believe this link is correct.

Comment: I just remembered that `time()` actually returns the time in seconds, so you can't use that to count ticks. You have to a millisec or higher clock, like `SDL_GetTicks`,  `clock_gettime` (linux), or the C++ `std::chrono`.

Comment: @ElderBug: I'm trying to use SDL_GetTicks but clicking X sets sleep_time to a negative number. See here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5iJwFO5-CZdSU5wZFNfSUhkMUE/view?usp=sharing Apologies I would use a shortened link but they don't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that I've found a solution to the problem with sleep_time being set to a negative when I press the X. Here's my new code:

```cpp
void run(){
    int SKIP_TICKS;
    long next_game_tick = SDL_GetTicks();
    long sleep_time = 0;

    while (!quit){
        SKIP_TICKS = 1000 / fps;

        updateGame();
        render();
        next_game_tick += SKIP_TICKS;
        sleep_time = next_game_tick - SDL_GetTicks();
        std::cout<<sleep_time<<std::endl;
        sleep_time *= 1000;
        if (sleep_time >= 0){
            usleep(sleep_time);
        }
        else{
            next_game_tick += SKIP_TICKS;
        }
    }
}
```

By using the if statement I avoid using usleep(sleep_time) if sleep_time is below zero. 
Thanks a lot to the people who helped me! :D